# Generic Method with object as argument in Java

Tags: java, generics, methods

There are two classes A and B which have similar methods. How to write a generic method that takes either one of the class object as argument and will be able to call the methods of that class.

Edit : I do not have control over class A, B. I get them only as arguments. So i cannot modify add them.

```
public class methods {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new methods().getName(new B());
        new methods().getName(new A());
    }

    private <T> void getName(T obj){
        // obj.getName()
    }
}

class A {

    String name = "ClassA";

    public void getName(){
        System.out.println(name);
    }

}

class B {

    String name = "ClassB";

    public void getName(){
        System.out.println(name);
    }

}
```

Comment: Program to an interface.

Comment: Make A and B implement a common interface, and use that interface as argument to your method. This is just polymorphism. You don't need generics for that.

Comment: After the edit: Only reflections could do that. There is no way for the compiler to handle different types of objects like that. They need to be of the same type.

Comment: @JackFlamp Or he can use `Object` as the parameter type and `instanceof` inside the method to check if it is `A` or `B`, but that sounds like pretty bad code (well, it actually is) :/.

Comment: @Tom sure, very 1.4.. Mr Schreiners way might be the best though.

Comment: So many bad solutions to an obvious design pattern. Incredible!

Comment: @JackFlamp i'm not sure whether its about 1.4 or something else. if a problem can be solved in a simpler way, why not go ahead with that?

Comment: @divine Jack wrote 1.4, because using `instanceof` is outdated and shouldn't be used in new code, even when that would be a "simple solution".

Comment: @Tom i understand the purpose of using design patterns. i don't understand what "outdated" means when basically we could arrive at  the solution(one of the solution of course) that is required for the OP. is instanceof operator deprecated?

Comment: @divine No it isn't and neither is `File` or `Date` (for example) and still both classes are outdated (and partly broken). That's why new code shouldn't use that anymore.

Comment: @Tom why is File outdated?

Answer (score 2):

If the two classes do not implement a common interface, you could use reflection, but this is not type safe (you won't get any compilation errors if A or B no longer support `getName()` and reflection is much slower than calling a method directly.

You could also implement two adapters that share an interface and use those (with generics):

```
interface Wrapper {
    String getName();
}

class WrapperA implements Wrapper {
    final private A a;
    public WrapperA(A wrapped) {
        this.a = wrapped;
    }
    @Override public String getName() {
        return a.getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: This pattern is named "adapter pattern".

Answer (score 1):

Below solution uses `instanceof operator` in the generic method to reach your output.

```
   public static void main(String[] args){
        new methods().getName(new B());
        new methods().getName(new A());
    }

    private <T> void getName(T obj) {
        if(obj instanceof B){
            ((B) obj).getName();
        }
        else{
            ((A) obj).getName();
        }
    }
```